# How to update the Entity framework after adding a new Table to the database in MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Alright first i apologize if i used any wrong terms.
my problem is that i created a database then i made the models out of it (database first approach) afterwards I've added a new table called "**accounts**" for example.

of course i cannot use it in the controller like

```
var x = db.accounts.Tolist();
```

because its not included in the models.

i tried to "update the model from the database" from the model design panel but it didn't create any new class for the new table..

any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that on the "Add" panel, you select the new table you want to add:

[image]

Sometimes I find that when I have problems it's easiest to just delete all the tables from the edmx and re-add them all, or even just to re-create the edmx in its entirety.

Comment: at the first time i checked it, but i cant check it if i try to update it again.

Comment: @user2962142 It must have added it in some capacity then. Try my second suggestion - delete all the tables and re-add them all.

Comment: Mansfield i tried it, even the deleted tables didnt come back.   @Tassadaque im adding a new table not modifying it.

Comment: @user2962142 Are you sure you're connecting to the right database?

Comment: @user2962142 Try creating a new .edmx from scratch then, and see what happens. Also, are you on sql server? If so, what version?

Comment: i tried to create a new ado.net entity model for the new table and it worked,and yes its "SQL Server Data Tools 11.1.20627.00"

Comment: @user2962142 Glad to hear it worked. Remember to accept the answer by clicking the green check mark to the left of the answer.